# Bigcommmere Api create product with images link

Tags: php, api, product, bigcommerce

I want to create product in bigcommerce store using bigcommerce Api. Following code works fine to create product in Bc store

`$product = array('name' => 'ABC Blocks', 'type' => 'physical', 'price' => '19.99', 'weight' => 2.3, 'categories' => array(26), 'availability' => 'available', 'is_visible' => true));
Bigcommerce_Api::createProduct($product);`

How can I pass images url ? I am trying following codes but unable to create

`$image = array('image_file'=>'https://developer.bigcommerce.com/assets/hero-image.png','is_thumbnail'=>false,'sort_order'=>1,'description'=>'');`

$product = array('name' => 'ABC Blocks', 'type' => 'physical', 'price' => '19.99', 'weight' => 2.3, 'categories' => array(26), 'availability' => 'available', 'is_visible' => true,'images' => array('image_file' => $image));

Bigcommerce_Api::createProduct($product);

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example structure from the api about how primary image data should look.

```
"primary_image": {
      "id": 247,
      "zoom_url": "https://cdn.url.path/bcapp/et7xe3pz/products/32/images/247/in_123__14581.1393831046.1280.1280.jpg?c=1",
      "thumbnail_url": "https://cdn.url.path/bcapp/et7xe3pz/products/32/images/247/in_123__14581.1393831046.220.290.jpg?c=1",
      "standard_url": "https://cdn.url.path/bcapp/et7xe3pz/products/32/images/247/in_123__14581.1393831046.386.513.jpg?c=1",
      "tiny_url": "https://cdn.url.path/bcapp/et7xe3pz/products/32/images/247/in_123__14581.1393831046.44.58.jpg?c=1"
    }
```

Use this to figure out your array structure.